# Selection of Collection API

Tags: java, collections

I need a source from where i can read when to use which Collection  i.e which Collection is best suitable for this particular  purpose with detail explanation.

Somebody please help me in this regard.i appreciate your support.

Comment: This has been asked before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940839/list-vs-queue-vs-set-of-collections-in-java

Comment: You can read the Java tutorial (google: java tutorial collections) and the relevant javadocs.

Comment: @lovewithjava and this is absolutely fine. Just get into a habit of searching for answers before asking questions. This will help you to become better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html) Java Collections tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I've always found [this](http://initbinder.com/bunker/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/collections.png) decision tree very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Book: [Java Generics and Collections](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do)